# Yii2: how to display data by id in Kartik Expand Row Column Widget

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Using Kartik Expand Row Column Widget to display data in collapsed row, I want to display data by id of that particular record,

actionindex()

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new CreateBookingsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $model = new CreateBookings();
        $data = CreateBookings::findOne($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
           $id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
           $model = CreateBookings::findOne($id);

           $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);
           $posted = current($_POST['CreateBookings']);
           $post = ['CreateBookings' => $posted];

           if ($model->load($post)) {
             $model->save();
             $output = '';
           }
           echo $out;
           return;
       }
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
 }
```

partial view :

```
<?php echo Html::encode($data->check_in);?>
<?php echo Html::encode($data->check_out);?>
```

Gridview

```
'columns' => [
                [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'value' => function ($model,$key,$index,$column) {
                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                },

                'detail' => function ($model,$key,$index,$column) {
                    $searchModel = new CreateBookingsSearch();
                    $searchModel->booking_id = $model ->id;
                    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expandrowview.php',[
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);
                },
            ],
```

Getting error `Undefined variable: id` when I pass `$data = CreateBookings::findOne($id);` in index. I need something like `public function actionView($id)` for index `public function actionIndex($id)` need to pass `id` in index

Answer (score 0):

> > > You can try this  (Use detailUrl)
> > >       In Gridview (Add a column anywhere)

```
      .  
      .
      'ExpandRowColumn'=>  
     [  
       'class' =>'\kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',  
       'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index,$column) {  
                 return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;  
        },  
       'detailUrl'=> Yii::$app->request->getBaseUrl().'..../expand-view',
     ], 
     .
     .
```

Here: The detailUrl will be the URl in the format of ../controllerName/expandView

> in Controller

```
    public function actionExpandView()  
        {  
         if(isset($_POST['expandRowKey'])) {  
             $model = ModelName::findOne($_POST['expandRowKey']);  
             $variable= $anydata; //anydata want to send in expanded view  
             return $this->renderPartial('_expandrowview.php',['anydata'=>$anydata,'model'=>$model]);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
           return '<div class="alert alert-danger">No data found</div>';  

        }  
        }  
    >>>expandRowKey is the first_column_data(may be id) of your model or table  
    *** you can send anydata using this method and can fetch data using simple php  
    print_r($anydata);  code
    on _expandrowview.php (view file) to make changes according to need..
```

Comment: Please try to add some sort of explanation alongside answers. This may be great code offering the perfect solution, but without some explanation it lacks any supporting evidence and makes it hard for others to learn what is going on or even generally learn for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sorry , but 
I Use a model  based from View  and $_POST['expandRowKey'] always return NULL.